# Generalizing binary left shift for octal representation without conversion

Tags: c++, binary, bit-manipulation, octal

Currently I have a few lines of code for working with binary strings in their decimal representation, namely I have functions to rotate the binary string to the left, flip a specific bit, flip all bits and reverse order of the binary string all working on the decimal representation. They are defined as follows:

```
inline u64 rotate_left(u64 n, u64 maxPower) {
    return (n >= maxPower) ? (((int64_t)n - (int64_t)maxPower) * 2 + 1) : n * 2;
}

inline bool checkBit(u64 n, int k) {
    return n & (1ULL << k);
}

inline u64 flip(u64 n, u64 maxBinaryNum) {
    return maxBinaryNum - n - 1;
}

inline u64 flip(u64 n, u64 kthPower, int k) {
    return checkBit(n, k) ? (int64_t(n) - (int64_t)kthPower) : (n + kthPower);
}

inline u64 reverseBits(u64 n, int L) {
    u64 rev = (lookup[n & 0xffULL] << 56) |                 // consider the first 8 bits
        (lookup[(n >> 8) & 0xffULL] << 48) |                // consider the next 8 bits
        (lookup[(n >> 16) & 0xffULL] << 40) |               // consider the next 8 bits
        (lookup[(n >> 24) & 0xffULL] << 32) |               // consider the next 8 bits
        (lookup[(n >> 32) & 0xffULL] << 24) |               // consider the next 8 bits
        (lookup[(n >> 40) & 0xffULL] << 16) |               // consider the next 8 bits
        (lookup[(n >> 48) & 0xffULL] << 8) |                // consider the next 8 bits
        (lookup[(n >> 54) & 0xffULL]);                      // consider last 8 bits
    return (rev >> (64 - L));                               // get back to the original maximal number
}
```

WIth the lookup[] list defined as:

```
#define R2(n) n, n + 2*64, n + 1*64, n + 3*64
#define R4(n) R2(n), R2(n + 2*16), R2(n + 1*16), R2(n + 3*16)
#define R6(n) R4(n), R4(n + 2*4 ), R4(n + 1*4 ), R4(n + 3*4 )
#define REVERSE_BITS R6(0), R6(2), R6(1), R6(3)

const u64 lookup[256] = { REVERSE_BITS };
```

All but the last one are easy to implement.

My question is whether you know any generalization of the above functions for the octal string of a number, while working only on the decimal representation as above? Obviously without doing a conversion and storing the octal string itself (mainly due to performance boost)
With flip() in octal code a would need to return the number with 8-x at the specified place in the string (for intstance: flip(2576, 2nd power, 2nd position) = 2376, i.e. 3 = 8-5).

I do understand that in octal representation the any similar formulas as for rotate_left or flip are not possible (maybe?), that is why I look for alternative implementation.
A possibility would be to represent each number in the octal string by their binary string, in other words to write: 29 --octal-> 35 --bin-> (011)(101)
Thus working on sets of binary numbers. Would that be a good idea?

If you have any suggestions for the code above for binary representation, I welcome any piece of advice.

Thanks in advance and sorry for the long post!

Comment: Octadecimal? Base 18? In octadecimal, `flip(3)` would be `F`. Base 8 is octal, not octadecimal.

Comment: Thanks @MSalters, you're right. I changed it, sorry for confusion

Comment: `u64` is not a decimal representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my understand of rotate_left, do not know my understand of question is correct, hope this will help you.

```cpp
// maxPower: 8
// n < maxPower:
// 0001 -> 0010
//
// n >= maxPower
// n:                      1011
// n - maxPower:           0011
// (n - maxPower) * 2:     0110
// (n - maxPower) * 2 + 1: 0111
inline u64 rotate_left(u64 n, u64 maxPower) {
  return (n >= maxPower) ? (((int64_t)n - (int64_t)maxPower) * 2 + 1) : n * 2;
}

// so rotate_left for octadecimal, example: 3 digit octadecimal rotate left.
//   0   1   1 ->   1   1   0
// 000 001 001 -> 001 001 000
//   4   4   0 ->   4   0   4
// 100 100 000 -> 100 000 100
// so, keep:
// first digit of octadecimal number is:
//   fisrt_digit = n & (7 << ((digit-1) * 3))
// other digit of octadecimal number is:
//   other_digit = n - first_digit
// example for 100 100 000:
//   first_digit is 100 000 000
//   other_digit is 000 100 000
// so rotate left result is:
//   (other_digit << 3) | (first_digit >> ((digit-1) * 3))
//
inline u64 rotate_left_oct(u64 n, u64 digit) {
  u64 rotate = 3 * (digit - 1);
  u64 first_digit = n & (7 << rotate);
  u64 other_digit = n - first_digit;
  return (other_digit << 3) | (first_digit >> rotate);
}
```

flip, for base 8, flip should be 7-x instead of 8-x:

```cpp
// oct flip same with binary flip:
//   (111)8  -> (001 001 001)2
// flip,
//   (666)8  -> (110 110 110)2
// this should be 7 - 1, not 8 - 1, indead.
//
inline u64 flip_oct(u64 n, u64 digit) {
  u64 maxNumber = (1 << (3 * digit)) - 1;
  assert(n <= maxNumber);
  return maxNumber - n;
}

// otc flip one digit
//   (111)8  -> (001 001 001)2
// flip 2nd number of it
//   (161)8  -> (001 110 001)2
// just need do xor of nth number of octadecimal number.
//
inline u64 flip_oct(u64 n, u64 nth, u64 digit) {
  return (7 << (3 * (nth - 1))) ^ n;
}
```

simple reverse.

```cpp
inline u64 reverse_oct(u64 n, u64 digit) {
  u64 m = 0;
  while (digit > 0) {
    m = (m << 3) | (n & 7);
    n = n >> 3;
    --digit;
  }
  return m;
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you very much @dyungwang
 This I can even generalized for hexadecimal etc.

Comment: Have you got an idea of how to write the reverseBits function for octal code? I.e. make a function which reverses the order of the octal string without converting to octal representation?

Comment: the reverse function is added, sorry for reply late

Answer (score 0):

@Qant123 :

A quick note regarding lazier approach on octal reversals :

```
   000001 010011 100101 110111
    0  1   2  3   4  5   6  7

1. 000001 010011 100101 110111 - sequential bit-string 000-111
2. 111110 101100 011010 001000 - bit-invert them
3. 000100 010110 001101 011111 - reverse the entire string all at once

   000100 010110 001101 011111
   [0][4] [2][6] [1][5] [3][7]
```

and voila, now you have the bit-reflected bit-string in sorted order.

The same approach also works for hex :

```
00000001001000110100010101100111 10001001101010111100110111101111
11111110110111001011101010011000 01110110010101000011001000010000
00001000010011000010101001101110 00011001010111010011101101111111

=>     [0] 8 [4] C [2] A [6] E ...
   ... [1] 9 [5] D [3] B [7] F

       [0]    8    [4]    C 
          [2]    A    [6]    E
       [1]    9    [5]    D 
          [3]    B    [7]    F
```

In fact, with a tiny bit of regex, you can ***mass*** produce these bit-reflected bit-strings using less than 5 cycles of a simple for-loop.

Since octal base has an odd amount of bits, any number `(mod 8)` with a palindromic bit-string wouldn't need to alter anything at all.

Luckily for octal, half of the values are palindromic -

```
   000 010 101 111
    0   2   5   7
```

So that's something one could consider including as an optimization shortcut - e.g. whenever 1st and 3rd bit matches (1st-bit XNOR 3rd-bit), then just copy it instead of having to reflect it.

——————————————

```
    # gawk profile, created Tue Nov 28 04:06:47 2023

        function r8v(__, ___, _, ____, _____, ______) {

     1      if (___-- < (_ += ++_))
                 return +__

     1      ____ = and( __ = +__,
                       ___ = (_ += _+_++) * ++_^(_____ = ___))
     1      ______ = _^-_____

     4      while (_____--)
     4          printf( "%d\f\r\t :: %15d | %15o | %-15o | %d\n",
                                            _____, __ *= _*_, __,
                       ____ += and(__, ___  = ++___*_ - !!_), ____)

     1      return ____*______
        }
```

> 

```
3
     ::          358208 |         1273500 | 210000          | 69632
2
     ::        22925312 |       127350000 | 7210000         | 1904640
1
     ::      1467219968 |     12735000000 | 37210000        | 8196096
0
     ::     93902077952 |   1273500000000 | 537210000       | 92082176
```

> 

```
12735
     | 5597
     | 22481
     | 53721
```

- I used* `* 8` and `* 64` here but those can easily be replaced by   `<< 3` and `<< 6`.

Only **ONE** single division (i.e. right-shift) has ever been performed throughout the code, and that's at the return statement.

But one can further optimize it by ensuring the intermediate values don't grow too large, and when it's all chained together, it's like :

```
# gawk profile, created Tue Nov 28 05:00:25 2023
{
    print __ = $(_ = _<_),
          __ = +((_) __),
         ___ = -++_ + (_^=_+ ++_),
        ____ = _*_

    printf("%o | %d | %o | %d | %o\n", __,
           _ = ____ * (____ * (\
               ____ * (____ *  and(__, ___)      + \
                              and(__, ___ *= _)) + \
                             and(__, ___ *= _))  + \
                            and(__, ___ *= _))   + \
                           and(__, ___ *  _), _, _ /= ____ * ____, _)
}
```

> 

```
12735 5597 7 64

12735 92082176 | 537210000 | 22481 | 53721
```

In shifting terms, it's either

```
  (((((n & (m)      ) << 6) + 
      (n & (m <<= 3)) << 6) + 
      (n & (m <<= 3)) << 6) + 
      (n & (m <<= 3)) << 6) + 
      (n & (m <<  3))      >> 12)
```

if you didn't mind mixing bitwise ops with addition, or purely bit-wise ops chain below :

```
  ((m & (m = ( 1 | ( 1 | (1 << 1))<<1) << 12)) | 
  ((n & (m >>=                      3 ))   |    
  ((n & (m >>=                 3 ))        |     
  ((n & (m >>=            3 ))             |      
   (n & (m >>  3))<< 6)<< 6)<< 6)<< 6) >> 12
```

========================

`@Qant123` :

This next chunk obviously isn't octal reversal, but just a quick showcase of what I meant by using floating point to deal with limitations many face daily (like in javascript).

> 

```
9007199254740881
    3
    31
```

---

```
  3 ::           131071
    377777
    0x1FFFF
    7.99999999838473740965127944946289062500000

  2 ::        536870911
    3777777777
    0x1FFFFFFF
    7.99999338388442993164062500000000000000000

  1 ::    2199023255551
    37777777777777
    0x1FFFFFFFFFF
    7.97290039062500000000000000000000000000000

  0 :: 9007199254740881
    377777777777777621
    0x1FFFFFFFFFFF91
    1.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

---

```
  9007199254740881
  9007199254740881
```

> 

```
  # gawk profile, created Wed Nov 29 05:50:59 2023

  function ______(__, _, ___, ____) {

      print __, ___ = int(__ /= (_ += ____=_+=_+= ++_)^(_+_ + !!_)), 
                ___ = ___*_ + int(__ = (__-___) * _)
      
      while (____--) {

          ___ = _ * (_ * (_ * (_ * ___ + \
               (___ = int(__ = (__ - int(__)) * _))) + \
                (___ = int(__ = (__   -  ___) * _))) + \
                 (___ = int(__ = (__  -  ___) * _))) + \
                         int(__ = (__ -  ___) * _)

          printf("%3d :: %16d\f\r\t%o\f\r\t0x%X\f\r\t%.41f\f\n",
                                        ____, ___, ___, ___, __)
       }
       return ___
  }
```

> 

By being prudent with temporary variables, even when including the the mandatory one for accepting input, only 4 are needed, processing 12-bits each cycle of the `while()` loop by doing *some*  measured amount of loop unrolling -

1. The iterator    (`____`)
2. The accumulator (`___`)
3. An agile scalar (`_ == 8`)
4. Original input  (`__`)

No constants were hard coded - they're all being generated on the fly algebraically, and the concepts of "iterator" and "accumulator" don't even really exist in `awk` lingo at all.

Instead of having the bits being shifted up-and-down, then up-and-down again, and again, here the price of the high cost op is paid up front, and everything from that point on only scale upwards.

This nested form (which I didn't invent) was supposed to be only for polynomials or something, but I find it to be such a great framework for just about anything else involving numeric-like values.

Let's take that same number we've been working with -

```
    octal chain 53721
```

Using the nested form, the conversion to decimal is REALLY streamlined -

```
   8 * (8 * (8 * (8 * (5) + 3) + 7) + 2) + 1      # arithmetic form

   1 | (2 | (7 | (3 | (5) << 3) << 3) << 3) << 3  # bit-shifting equivalent
```

Personally I like the first form more because the digits can remain in big-endian visual order.

Comment: that is not really what I needed for the reversing of octal string. If I understand correctly, your approach reverses the 3-bit string in each block, whereas I need to reverse the whole string using binary operations. For instance, 12735=(001)(010)(111)(011)(101) should be 53721=(101)(011)(111)(010)(001). Unless you refer to the implementation of the flip function, which I think is faster in che.wang implementation (see answer above)

Comment: @Qant123 : his approach also requires pre-calculating the total number of digits ahead of time, which means if you already knew ahead of time it's gonna be 5, you can start with a bit-mask at level (instead of `n & 7`, you do `n & 28672` for 4 trailing octals.), then each round you UPSHIFT the input and grab the digits  "coming up" to you : 1…2….7….3….5….. and simply perform 1 final downshift at the end of the loop, AS LONG AS  the process not overflowing your data type. - see my modified answer above on how that works

Comment: I see. Indeed that seems faster (I did not understand previously what you meant), I'll do a performance comparison. Thank you!

Comment: @Qant123 : there's actually even YET another approach I use for `awk` but it's rather unconventional - as long as the input can safely be represented by 53-bit double-precision floating point in the backend, what I do is actually pre-downshift the entire thing to be a decimal value less than 2. Then the rest of the time it's simply adding things back and multiplying. So only one single division performed. That method I don't even need to up-shift the down-shift any bit-masks cuz each round I multiply the residual input to have up to 1 octal worth "above water", meaning, the zero-th power line…

Comment: ….. i grab them out, and subtract it out from the rest of the input. It's a very whacko way of using basic algebraic operations over floating point to get around the lack of native `uint64` data type.  I appended my answer above with a semi proof of concept